# my firebase version is not support with my onesignal plugin version I a lot of way to config this but the problem is still exist

Tags: firebase, flutter, build.gradle, onesignal

Launching lib\main.dart on Pixel 3 XL in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:[10.2.1, 17.3.99].
> Required by:
> project :app > com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.15.3
> > Skipped due to earlier error
> Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:[15.0.0, 16.0.99].
> Required by:
> project :app > com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.15.3
> > Skipped due to earlier error
> Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:[10.2.1, 16.1.99].
> Required by:
> project :app > com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.15.3
> > Skipped due to earlier error

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 24s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                       145.7s (!)

Answer (score 0):

Try Going to File >  `Invalidate Caches/Restart` and see if it works for you.